# Selenium server couldn't be started - Running Rscript

Tags: r, ubuntu, selenium-webdriver, cron, rselenium

I'm using ***Ubuntu 20.04*** to run Rstudio Server.

I installed Selenium and all the others drivers to run the RSelenium package in the Rstudio-Server. It worked very well.

Now i'm trying to run the Rscript every day using the cron function from Ubuntu terminal.

But is not completing the first code in the Rscript:

> ```
> drv <- rsDriver(remoteServerAddr = "localhost",browser = "firefox", port = 4445L, verbose = T)
> ```

That's the log result from the Linux Terminal:

> ```
> checking Selenium Server versions:
> BEGIN: PREDOWNLOAD
> BEGIN: DOWNLOAD
> BEGIN: POSTDOWNLOAD
> checking chromedriver versions:
> BEGIN: PREDOWNLOAD
> BEGIN: DOWNLOAD
> BEGIN: POSTDOWNLOAD
> checking geckodriver versions:
> BEGIN: PREDOWNLOAD
> BEGIN: DOWNLOAD
> BEGIN: POSTDOWNLOAD
> checking phantomjs versions:
> BEGIN: PREDOWNLOAD
> BEGIN: DOWNLOAD
> BEGIN: POSTDOWNLOAD
> Error in wdman::selenium(port = port, verbose = verbose, version = version,  :
> Selenium server  couldn't be started
> Calls: rsDriver -\> \<Anonymous\>
> Execution halted
> ```

**How do i solve it?**

Thanks in advance

I'd like to run the Rscript in the Linux command line because i will use to run using cron.

Thanks in advance